# How to get the same result with htpasswd using PHP?

Tags: php, crypt, .htpasswd

I'm using a Debian 7.0 with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli).

I need to build an htpasswd files from a form (data stored with MySQL).

I tried that but didn't work:

```
$hash = crypt($_POST['password'], base64_encode($_POST['password'])); //didn't work

$hash = crypt($_POST['password']); //didn't work

$hash = crypt($_POST['password'], substr($_POST['password'])); //didn't work



$cset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789./"; 
$salt = ""; 
for ($i=0; $i<CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH; $i++) ``
    $salt .= substr($cset, rand() & 63, 1); 
$hash = crypt($_POST['password'], $salt); // didn't work
```

Someone can explain me how i can get the same result as htpasswd using PHP ? It's depend on my debian ? My /usr/bin/htpasswd script ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't work*? Is it because generated values are different? `htpasswd` use a random salt, thus generated values will always be different.

Comment: Hi, I mean i can't access folder with the apache's authentification (htaccess). I know all values will be different. But i can't perform a correct login :(*

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's seem to be correct ! So, a simple salt like 'aa' do the stuff ..

Comment: I removed my comment instead of editing it to fix a typo... Answer your own question and mark it as solved when you're done ;)

Comment: I can't answer now ... Need to wait 7h :(. 

So i post here : 

 Guillaume Poussel give me the solution:

I need to use a simple salt like 'aa'. 

So my code:

     $hash = crypt($_POST['password'], 'aa');

And now, i can login correctly !